# exception : connection reset in java if the response take more than 5 min from client using httpclient get request

Tags: java, rest, connection, httpclient, reset

Getting Expection connection reset when using httpclient to get response from REST API ,which takes more than 5 minutes for respose.

Using java 1.7

when i tried with postman , getting response after 6 min .

could you please help me to resolve the issue .

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(600000)
.setSocketTimeout(600000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(600000).build();


SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom().setSoKeepAlive(true)
.setSoTimeout(600000).build();
```

Expecting response even if it takes more than 5 minutes , how to avoid connection reset . I have tried several ways as i included nothing worked .

Your help is much appreciated .

Comment: did you check the server settings on which the API resides. Probably the server terminates the requests which are greater than 5 minutes

Comment: I just saw some comments in google , like if server terminates the connection , the exception will be like Connection rest by peer . But I'm not sure .      In my case its is Exception : Connection reset .                   Thanks for helping .

Comment: Hi Experts , could any help on this . If I use curl command , able to get response which takes around 6 minutes , but fails with httpsclient alone if the response take exactly more than 5 minutes . Do I need to change any configuration apart from the above ones I mentioned , like ssotimout .....